# older Linux kernel does not boot with newer distro

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, initramfs

I have to install a self compiled 4.17 kernel on a new Ubuntu 21.04 distro and run into the issue, that the system seems to be stuck after printing "Loading initial ramdisk...".
Same problem occurs for the recovery boot option of that kernel. A new, self compiled 5.11 kernel can be installed and booted without any problems and a 4.17 kernel installed by deb file also boots without problems.

I can not receive any more information why the boot fails. journaldevctl does not collect any logs of the failed boot. Booting without "quiet" and with "loglevel=7" parameter does not print further information.

I also tried an older gcc version and used the config of the 4.17 kernel installed by deb file without any success. Is there anything I miss or is using an older kernel with a newer distro a problem in general?

Comment: One step to figure it out: "a 4.17 kernel installed by deb file also boots without problems" => self compile your kernel with the same configure options as the one which is working. If it works that means you need some mandatory options.

Comment: @A.B I tried that, but the problem keeps the same.